# Spring MVC, Maven, Pivotal tc Server HTML 404 Not Found error

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

Following a spring mvc tutorial and I am getting the  error

**HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

Can anyone identify whats missing or can point me in the right direction?

Using spring tools suit 3.9.o and pivotal tc server and maven

**HomeController.java**

```
    package com.infiniteskills.mvc;

     import java.text.DateFormat;
     import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.Locale;

     import org.slf4j.Logger;
     import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
     import org.springframework.ui.Model;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

     /**
      * Handles requests for the application home page.
      */
      @Controller
      public class HomeController {

        private static final Logger logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

        /**
         * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
            logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = 
     DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG,locale);

            String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

            return "home";
        }

          }
```

**POM.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.infiniteskills</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc</artifactId>
    <name>hello-world</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
       <java-version>1.6</java-version>
       <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
       <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
       <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
      </properties>
    <dependencies>
     <!-- Spring -->
         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>
```

**Web.xml**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

            <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
        <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
          </context-param>

         <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
             <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
               </listener>

           <!-- Processes application requests -->
           <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
         </servlet>

           <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>

         </web-app>
```

**servlet-content.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

       <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

       <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
```

**root-context.xml**

```
       <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
       <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

       <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
           <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.infiniteskills.mvc" />



     </beans:beans>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

      <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

       </beans>
```

Comment: Try these options: 1) Right click on the project, deployment assembly, see if maven dependencies are added. 2) Right click on the project, project facets, add the pivotaltc server as the runtime.

Comment: In spring tools suite the deployment assembly is found by right clicking project > preferences > deployment assembly

Maven Dependencies are already added 

Pivotal tc server is also set for runtime

Comment: I had this issue too, and I solved this by deleting maven repositories and let to re-download dependencies of project by right-click on project -> maven -> update Project...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `@RequestMapping("/homeController")` after `@Controller` for mapping of Controller. and use `@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)` before method.
and url will b : `http://localhost:8080/project-name/homeController/hello` and use GET method.

Comment: @RequestMapping annotation (above home method) is set after the @controller(above class) annotation is set.

Why would I need to set the value as '/hello'? The default request method is GET so there is no need to explicitly set that and I would like the default path to ("/") to point to the home controller so I don't have to enter an extended url path.

Comment: i you dont want to use `set the value as '/hello'` then remove  `value` it will take default `/`. and can you try to move your servlet-content.xml into WEB-INF and use `<param-value>classpath:servlet-content.xml</param-value>` into web.xml.